# pass core data record from uiview

Tags: core-data, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I've a little issue in my app. my app is based on core data using magical record.

In my first view ( a tableview) I have all the data, when one of the cell is tapped, it open the second view (detail UIview).

But i don't have enough space to show all the detail so i create a second detail view from the first one ( I don't want a scroll view).

the segue between the tableView and the firstDetailView work perfectly

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        DetailViewController*dvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        dvc.indice = indexPath.row;
    }
}
```

But when I go to the second detail UIview I always get the detail of the first record in the tableview. I think the problem is in the prepareForSegue method, but I can't figure out how to solve it,

Somebody could help me??

Comment: Post your code for the prepareForSegue to the secondDetailView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created another property in the second detail view and set it equal to the property "indice" of the first detail view

```
   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showMaking"]) {


        DettaglioPreferito2*dvc = segue.destinationViewController;

        dvc.indiceDue = self.indice;

    }
}
```